# how to extract comma separated values separately in Erlang

Tags: erlang, mnesia

I have inserted the comma separated values into `mnesia` table column as `{"11,1,15"}`

After retrieving from table Now i need to extract these comma separated values. while extracting these `11`,`1`,`15` as separate values, I am getting problem, because it returning value in below format.

```
49 | 1,1,12.
```

But here i need them separately as integer digits.

Can you point me in correct direction? where I am making mistake?

Answer (score 6):

If you want to convert a string of comma separated integers into a list of integers, this can help:

```
1> String = "11,1,15".
"11,1,15"
2> [list_to_integer(I) || I <- string:tokens(String,",")].
[11,1,15]
```